# CRM 2011 - Save incident changes before resolve

Tags: c#, javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have this javascript resolve code that it's called when the "Resolve" button is pressed on a case.

```
function CloseIncidentRequest(incidentId) {
    var requestMain = ""
    requestMain += "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">";
    requestMain += "  <s:Body>";
    requestMain += "    <Execute xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">";
    requestMain += "      <request i:type=\"b:CloseIncidentRequest\" xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts\" xmlns:b=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2011/Contracts\">";
    requestMain += "        <a:Parameters xmlns:c=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic\">";
    requestMain += "          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    requestMain += "            <c:key>IncidentResolution</c:key>";
    requestMain += "            <c:value i:type=\"a:Entity\">";
    requestMain += "              <a:Attributes>";
    requestMain += "                <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    requestMain += "                  <c:key>incidentid</c:key>";
    requestMain += "                  <c:value i:type=\"a:EntityReference\">";
    requestMain += "                    <a:Id>" + incidentId + "</a:Id>";
    requestMain += "                    <a:LogicalName>incident</a:LogicalName>";
    requestMain += "                    <a:Name i:nil=\"true\" />";
    requestMain += "                  </c:value>";
    requestMain += "                </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    requestMain += "                <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    requestMain += "                  <c:key>subject</c:key>";
    requestMain += "                  <c:value i:type=\"d:string\" xmlns:d=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">Parent Case has been resolved</c:value>";
    requestMain += "                </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    requestMain += "              </a:Attributes>";
    requestMain += "              <a:EntityState i:nil=\"true\" />";
    requestMain += "              <a:FormattedValues />";
    requestMain += "              <a:Id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</a:Id>";
    requestMain += "              <a:LogicalName>incidentresolution</a:LogicalName>";
    requestMain += "              <a:RelatedEntities />";
    requestMain += "            </c:value>";
    requestMain += "          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    requestMain += "          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    requestMain += "            <c:key>Status</c:key>";
    requestMain += "            <c:value i:type=\"a:OptionSetValue\">";
    requestMain += "              <a:Value>140310001</a:Value>";
    requestMain += "            </c:value>";
    requestMain += "          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    requestMain += "        </a:Parameters>";
    requestMain += "        <a:RequestId i:nil=\"true\" />";
    requestMain += "        <a:RequestName>CloseIncident</a:RequestName>";
    requestMain += "      </request>";
    requestMain += "    </Execute>";
    requestMain += "  </s:Body>";
    requestMain += "</s:Envelope>";

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();
    var oDataEndpointUrl = serverUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web";
    req.open("POST", oDataEndpointUrl, false)
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Execute");
    req.send(requestMain);

    if (req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("faultstring").length == 0)
        window.location.reload(true);
    else
        alert(req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("faultstring")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
```

I need to save the **non-saved changes** done to the case (in case there are any) **before resolving it**.
I tried to add this

```
Xrm.Page.data.entity.save("save");
```

before the calling of the CloseIncidentRequest function but its not working, the changes are lost and the case is resolved. I also tried with "saveandclose" but it didn't do the trick either. I also tried refreshing the page after the saving and before the resolve, but it also didn't work.

I as well have a plugin that fires on the "OnClose" event of the case, but I didn't know a way to retrieve the non-saved changes done to the case I am trying to resolve.

I could go either way, from javascript or from plugin. I just need to save the changes do they won't be lost.

Any ideas that might help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to save the case as following.

```
Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
```

**Update**

Put the following javascript on save event of the form. I have not tested so you might need to tweak it.

```
function FrmOnSave(prmContext) {
    // Local variable to store value indicating how the save event was initiated by the user.
    var wod_SaveMode, wod_SaveEventVal;

    // Change the Save Event Value as per required Save Event
    wod_SaveEventVal = 5;

    if (prmContext != null && prmContext.getEventArgs() != null) {

            wod_SaveMode = prmContext.getEventArgs().getSaveMode();
            if (wod_SaveMode == wod_SaveEventVal) {

                // Write your validation code here
                var ismodified = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getIsDirty();
                if(ismodified == true)
                {
                 alert("please save the changes first");
                 prmContext.getEventArgs().preventDefault();
                }                   
        }
    }
}
```

For reference please go through [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4122.dynamics-crm-2011-perform-jscript-validations-on-entity-form-before-execution-of-special-events.aspx) blog.

Comment: I think You need to override the `Case Close` event.

Comment: Go through this blog, I am sure you will get an idea: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4122.dynamics-crm-2011-perform-jscript-validations-on-entity-form-before-execution-of-special-events.aspx

Comment: I can't seem to understand how this would help me.. since I don't need a validation, I need my non-saved data to be saved if the user attemtps to resolve the case without saving tha changes first..